# Numerical transformation in javascript and math operation

Tags: javascript, numbers, transformation, numerical

Here is the code:

```js
alert(typeof(+"13t"));
alert(1 + (+"13t"));
```

Why in the first line the output is "number"
And in the second line the output is "NaN"??

Comment: No offense, but we already had like million of questions about converting types in javascript and it always boils to RFTM. Just read MDN docs about it.

Comment: What does `(+"13t")` return? :) That would answer your question.

Comment: @TomášZato Quick questions needs quick answer.

Comment: Your perceived need for a quick answer isn't at all relevant here. Perform basic research.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value `NaN` *is* a number. Even though `NaN` means "not a number", it's still got the data type "number".

The string `"13t"` when coerced to a number value yields `NaN`, unsurprisingly. Adding `1` to `NaN` also yields `NaN`.

Answer (score 3):

That is because

```
typeof NaN; //outpute "number"
```

and

```
+"13t" //is NaN
```

And second one is trying to add `1` to `NaN`, which is still `NaN`.